# User-sortable table with material-ui<

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

We are using material-ui as our UI library and I need to create table where user will be able to specify order of rows. So I need library like https://jqueryui.com/sortable/

I found react-sortable: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-sortable

Does anybody have expirience with combination of react-sortable and material-ui libraries? Are there any drawbacks?

Thank you!

Comment: If you're using material-ui v1, you might want to take a look at the [sortable table example in their docs](https://material-ui-next.com/demos/tables/#sorting-amp-selecting).

Comment: That is something different - it does sort table by column values. What I need is something where user alone can specity order of rows regardless of their content. Like libraries in the problem description.

I have tried using react-sortable and so far it works fine.